# jslint-maven-plugin 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT repository

Tags: maven, jslint

I can only find 1.0.1 - it's a git world and I *really* hope I don't have to install subversion to check out the code and build it myself :-(

The usage page http://www.mojohaus.org/jslint-maven-plugin/usage.html says 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT - where's the maven repository<strike>, a**holes</strike>?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using jslint4java instead:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.jslint4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>jslint4java-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
```

This kind of slackyness only scares off potential users, CodeHaus/Mojo ...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT has not been released.

So ff you do not want to install a SVN client, use [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html):

```
git-svn clone http://svn.example.com/svn/project
```